# In Rapidminer after splitting a column how do I change the type of the new column column?

Tags: rapidminer

Very new to RM making headway slowly.

I have split a column such that the new column is a column of numbers this field is set automatically to `polynomial`.

How do I set it to `Numerical` or even better `Integer`?

I have tried `Geuss Type` but this did not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess Types should work. If it doesn't it could be that one of the values hasn't been split properly and is still a nominal. Parse Numbers will also work but again will not cope with nominals.

Comment: Turns out I had NA for null values but in RM it needs to be NaN.  After making this conversion the Guess Type operator worked. Thanks for the responce.